# How to connect Mysql server with Asp.net 2010

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

how ro avoid 'MySQL.Data' could not be found error in visual studio 2010?
 please help me

Comment: It sounds like you're just missing an assembly reference. If that's not the case, please give us more details - the code, the references you've got set up etc.

Answer (score 2):

You need to download and install the MySql Connector/Net.

You can get it here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/